# How to stop Exchange from automatically converting plain text emails to HTML?

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2003

I've set up an Exchange 2003 mailbox for emails that will be parsed by my code. The emails are sent as plain text and my code expects to receive them as plain text. However, it appears that Exchange is automatically converting them to HTML. How do I stop it from doing that and just receive the email the way it was sent?

The reason I believe it's Exchange doing the conversion is because the received email looks like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 6.5.7654.12">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->
(then the actual contents, but with HTML markup)
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: since this plagues me: i've opened a corresponding SF question. http://serverfault.com/questions/10347/how-to-stop-exchange-2007-from-automatically-converting-plain-text-emails-to-html

Comment: How is your application retrieving the mails?

Comment: +1 for the question.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the settings for the POP virtual server, there is an option for overriding the MIME encoding of the messages, where you can specify text, html, or both.

In Exchange System Manager:

Servers -> "YOUR SERVER" -> Protocols -> POP3 -> Virtual Server -> Properties -> Message Format tab

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. The email is still received as HTML. :(

Answer (score 1):

Before setting up all the rules as per the next section, it is worth confirming this option on your Exchange server, if you have access.

Start the Exchange System Manager program.

Expand “Global Settings”, and then click “Internet Message Formats”.

In the right pane, double-click your Internet message formats object.

Now Click Advanced then Set Rich Text Editor Radio Button to Never.  Press Ok.

I found the answer using:

http://help.affinitylive.com/setup/automatic-email-capture/exchange-2003/

Let us know if this fixes it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.